# How to retrieve necessary fields from ModelForms and pass them to views.py properly?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Short background of whole idea: I'm trying to create landing page and for backend I use Python/Django3 framework. I need to create form with such fields as name, surname, email, mobile number and address of customer.

I've decided to save all the information that the user enters in the database, and also send it to my email. In order to connect database to forms I use **ModelForms** in **forms.py** section (all the required code will be shown below). In order to connect my email to form I use **send_mail** function from **django.core.mail**.

So when a user fills out his form, he is redirected to the 'thank you' page and all the information from the form is saved in the database and sent to my email.

But when I finally wrote the code and started to test functionality, I found out that when I hit **'submit'** form button, error **<type object 'ClientInfoForm' has no attribute 'cleaned_data'>** is raised.

I suppose, that method **cleaned_data** is wrong in my case and I have to replace it with something else but I don't know with what exactly. All the code will be placed below and any help will be helpful. Thank you!
**Models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
class ClientInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=264)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Client: {self.name} {self.surname}'
```

**Forms.py file**

```
from django import forms
from landing_page.models import ClientInfo

class ClientInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = ClientInfo
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from landing_page.forms import ClientInfoForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'landing_page/thanks.html')



def index(request):

    form = ClientInfoForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientInfoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            name = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['name']
            surname = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['surname']
            email = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['email']
            mobile_number = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
            address = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['address']


            send_mail(
                f'New client: {name} {surname}',
                f'Client Name: {name}\nClient Surname: {surname}\nClient email: {email}\n'
                f'Client Mobile Number: {mobile_number}\nClient address: {address}',
                email,
                ['zombe@yandex.ru'],
            )

            return thanks(request)

        else:
            print('ERROR FORM INVALID')

    return render(request, 'landing_page/index.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys, in case you all interested I found out what was the actual problem. 
**I just had to change this code below**

```
name = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['name']
surname = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['surname']
email = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['email']
mobile_number = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
address = ClientInfoForm.cleaned_data['address']
```

**To this version**

```
name = form.cleaned_data['name']
surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
email = form.cleaned_data['email']
mobile_number = form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
address = form.cleaned_data['address']
```